# How to remove subscriber from list

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I try to figure out how unsubscribe an Subscriber from a List.

We use FuelSDK and RestAPI.

any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set their status to **Unsubscribed** or better, log an UnsubEvent.

**Reference**: [Unsubscribing and Logging an UnsubEvent with a LogUnsubEvent Execute Call](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/unsubscribing-and-logging-an-unsubevent-with-a-logunsubevent-execute-call.html)